# JBoss Developer Studio Portlet Implementation Library

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I followed this [tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/7.0/pdf/JBoss_Portlet_Tools_User_Guide/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio-7.0-JBoss_Portlet_Tools_User_Guide-en-US.pdf). On page 11 I should use the Portlet Implementation Library type "Portlet Target Runtime Provider". But I can only choose betwwen "User Library" and "Disbale Library Configuration".

Answer (score 0):

Its because your using the basic server rather than the portal bundle. You need to download jboss-portal-2.7.2 (instead of maybe jboss-4.2.3.GA?). Then 'Portlet Target Runtime Provider' becomes available.